# Unable to create a branch on my local repo

Tags: git, github, git-branch

please treat me as a beginner to git as I just started learning more of it.

I have installed git in my machine and initiated a local git repo using the "git init" command.

Added a couple of text files in the git local repo and using the "git add ." command I added the newly added files to the staging area.

Now I am wanting to check the current branch using the "git branch" command but it says nothing and there is no response on the command prompt.
even if I am trying to create a new branch too I am unable to do so.

Can someone explain to me what is the issue here

Comment: Please copy and paste your entire actual “conversation” with the command line directly into the question. It is likely you are in some edit mode.

Comment: do : git status 
and put result here

Answer (score 0):

if you have successfully initialized your project with git, then you can  run below command.

```
 1. git status // this command show which branch  you are right now and all changes files.

 2.git add . // this command add all chnages file to staging area
      or
   git add file_name // give complete file path which show after executing git status command

 You can check your  added file in staging area using command
 3. git status // you always run this command for cross check which branch  you are right now and all added files.

 Now commit your files using command
 4. git commit -m "commit message"

 if you want to push this branch code to remote repo, you can use 
 5. git push origin YOUR_CURRENT_WORKING_BRANCH_NAME 

 If you are working in any other branch than master. checkout master first then create your other branch.
 6. git checkout master 
 
 Now you can create and switch to that branch in one command using
 7. git checkout -b YOUR_DESIRE_BRANCH_NAME
```